# Gitlab CI runner firewall configuration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running a Gitlab CI runner on AWS EC2. I need to know which ports are required to be open so that I would not need to allow all incoming traffic to the server.

Currently, I have allowed all incoming traffic which is a security concern and when I change it to only SSH then the runner does not work. Which ports are required to be open for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The runner does not require any inbound connections. The runner can operate with outbound/established connections only.

If your firewall also controls outbound/established connections, you'll need to make sure you allow outbound and established connections to your GitLab server. Usually just 22 for SSH and 80/443 HTTP/HTTPS, but this can change depending on your server configuration.